# How do I get Guake(terminal) to report the correct terminal?

Tags: command-line, environment-variables, gnu-screen, guake

I've been using Guake on my laptop and my desktop and everything has been fine until I recently bought a new HD and did a fresh install of Ubuntu 10.10.

I installed Guake and it works fine except for when I try to use GNU `screen`:

```
wayne@arglefraster:~$ screen -xRR
Please set a terminal type.
wayne@arglefraster:~$ echo $TERM
dumb
```

In my Guake config preferences I have /bin/bash set as my default interpreter - which is the same thing that I have on my laptop. Both xterm and gnome-terminal shows `xterm` as the `TERM` value, and even <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> shows `linux`.

So how do I get Guake to use the proper TERM value so I can avoid having to `export TERM=xterm` in my Guake every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are experiencing this [launchpad bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/guake/+bug/621927).

Given that you are now using the unsupported 10.10, this will not be fixed for this release.  A workaround is the best you can expect unless you install and compile your own later version of Guake and GNU screen.

Post #73 gives a suggested workaround - reproduced below:

```
echo "export TERM=xterm" | sudo tee /etc/profile.d/set_term.sh && source /etc/profile
```

Alternatively add:

```
[ "$TERM" = dumb ] && export TERM=xterm
```

to your `~/.bashrc`